# How add button (or other Widget) upon the showModalBottomSheet in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

On the left hand side is the design. On the right hand side my Flutter application where I want to build this design:

[image]

Whatever I try, I don't get the button on top of the line.

The last thing I have tried is a Stacked widget:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    ...
  ),
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          child: Image.asset('assets/images/add.png'),
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
              colors: <Color>[
                CustomColors.PurpleLight,
                CustomColors.PurpleDark,
              ],
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(50.0),
            ),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: CustomColors.PurpleShadow,
                blurRadius: 10.0,
                spreadRadius: 5.0,
                offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 50),
            Text('Add new task'),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              textColor: Colors.white,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              ),
              child: Container(),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

I hope you have some tip or a good solution :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use shape of showModalBottomSheet parameter, instead of it make showModalBottomSheet transparent then add background to stack as one of the children and change its shape. And you can put button inside the column.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  _onPressed() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 100,
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.elliptical(150, 30)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/add.png'),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                        end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        colors: <Color>[
                          Colors.red,
                          Colors.blue,
                        ],
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(50.0),
                      ),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.purple,
                          blurRadius: 10.0,
                          spreadRadius: 5.0,
                          offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 50),
                  Text('Add new task'),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    child: Container(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: RaisedButton(
      onPressed: _onPressed,
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! So simple. At first I just used the 'RoundedRectangleBorder' in the BottomSheet because it was specially new her fore.

Comment: Your welcome, pls upvote the answer if it's good. The stackoverflow rating system doesn't count accepted answers in specific tag rating.

Comment: I wish I could give you more than one upvote!